# Add username, profile picture, etc to sign up with Firebase (Swift 2)

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

Hey guys I've been watching some courses of making social apps and all of them were made with Parse, so now that I can't use it for the future because is shutting down I'm using Firebase.

The thing is Firebase has some information about authenticate user with email and password and I don't know how to send the username, profile picture, bio, etc's user information to Firebase. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: How about you still use parse, by deploying to heroku? That has a very good documentation

Comment: This is a really broad question. When you say 'send it to Firebase' what does that mean? Have you gone through the Firebase documentation, especially the [Authentication - Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) section?

Comment: Mean, what I'm saying is that the Firebase's guide teaches you how to autheticate with email and password, but can i do it also with the profile image and username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can authenticate the user https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth, then store the user information under the user's uid key in the realtime database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data.

This is the documentation on structuring databases:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree

Let me know if you would like any more information

I'm also switching from Parse to Firebase and was wondering the same thing.