# Value for user's phoneNumber on firebase/auth

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying get to the value for a users phoneNumber using this code:

```
let userPhoneNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber
let messageDictionary = ["sender": userPhoneNumber, "messageBody": messageTextField.text!]
```

But it keeps coming up as nil. Outside of saving the phoneNumber upon user's sign in during the initial verification process, how can I access the value for the user's phoneNumber at any time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the user values before you can retrieve them. However, I'm not sure if you can set a custom field like a phone number, but if you can it would work like this.

```
let phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextField.text!

let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

Alternatively, you could save the user phone number to userDefaults and retrieve it from there.

```
let defaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")

// To get phoneNumber
let pNumber = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "phoneNumber")
```

Lastly, you could upload the information to your  [Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516729/add-username-profile-picture-etc-to-sign-up-with-firebase-swift-2)

Comment: I'm able to save the phoneNumber as a userDefault, but I want to be able to access that value using Firebase speak. With email-auth I can access the value for a user's email with this:
    let userEmail = Auth.auth()?.currentUser?.email
    let messageDictionary = ["sender": Usermail, 
    "messageBody": messageTextfield.text!]
I was hoping that I'd be able to access the value for user phoneNumber using phoneAuth just as easily as I would get the email value with emailAuth. FireBase's Authentication page values phoneNumber as "Identifier", I need that identifier value.

Comment: Are you using Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ? If you aren't then you can save the phone number there. It won't really make sense, but you could easily retrieve it. However, I think if you want it to be more Firebase that you should store the users information in the database and retrieve it when the user signs in.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice solution, I'll just save the phoneNumber as the value for Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber which is currently set to nil. Thanks.

Comment: ...turns out -Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber- is immutable. I got this error when trying to assign the user's phoneNumber: "Cannot assign to property: 'phoneNumber' is immutable"
Funny, I thought only variables could be optional... There are a couple work arounds to get the values I need so I think I'll fare out okay. Thanks.